# Como colocar um overflow numa div com script para deixar listas fixas no cabeçalho?

Tags: javascript, css, rolamento

Olá, estou tentando acrescentar um `overflow:scroll` no meu projeto, mas isso invalida o script que deixa a `div` `marker` fixa no topo até chegar na próxima `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5cC83/5/

Se tirar o overflow:scroll do css na `.divContexto` o código funciona corretamente com a div `.marker` ficando fixa no topo da div contexto ao rolar a página. Mas como terão vários blocos na pagina que irei criar eu preciso fazer funcionar mesmo com `overflow:scroll`.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia colocar uma div a mais englobando a .divContexto para que o pai tenha o scroll?

Em jQuery você poderia fazer algo como

```
$(".divContexto").wrap("rolagem");
```

E no CSS a div .rolagem que teria o scroll.